# How to make browser navigation work in Angular SSR application?

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-routing, server-side-rendering

So, I have this Angular SSR application hosted on a nginx server.
Scenario is -:

1. There is list page where I make api call to get data and create links to other pages.
2. Then, on clicking any link it goes to another page and fetch data.
3. Now if I use browser back to navigate back to list page there is no data because no api calls were made.

**Note**: -

***Works fine in local host***.

**In nginx production server, works fine if I use any other button instead of browser back for navigating back**.

Please let me know which part of code is needed.
Thanks.

**Nginx conf:**

```
server {
    server_name mydemosite;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ncladmin/demosite/mydemosite;
    }

    #location /pages/ {
    #    include proxy_params;
    #    proxy_pass mydemourl;
    #    proxy_set_header Host mydemogurl;
    #}

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:home/ncladmin/mydemosite/mydemosite.sock;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydemosite/fullchain.pem;$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydemosite/privkey.pe$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = mydemosite) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mydemosite;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Build**

Initial Chunk Files               | Names         |      Size
main.61fa0bcbd5bdfcba15eb.js      | main          | 283.33 kB
styles.9ead987bd4edd86dd57c.css   | styles        | 125.30 kB
polyfills.297e52098208f3025ef2.js | polyfills     |  36.66 kB
runtime.5dfcb54aae720d1a33d0.js   | runtime       |   2.27 kB

| Initial Total | 447.56 kB

Lazy Chunk Files                  | Names         |      Size

1.83954724103e60c4ed8c.js         | -             | 142.25 kB

5.c5db6147620ba74d2da0.js         | -             |  32.53 kB

6.43c0aec6f6d8bd88beb8.js         | -             |   3.94 kB

Build at: 2021-07-02T09:00:13.003Z - Hash: ceb338239b5ec146751f - Time: 61182ms

✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files                                                            | Names                                                                       |      Size
main.js                                                                        | main                                                                        |   2.73 MB                                                                               | Initial Total                                                               |   2.73 MB

Lazy Chunk Files                                                               | Names                                                                       |      Size

vendors~modules-content-pages-content-pages-module~modules-home-home-module.js | vendors~modules-content-pages-content-pages-module~modules-home-home-module | 357.24 kB

modules-content-pages-content-pages-module~modules-home-home-module.js         | modules-content-pages-content-pages-module~modules-home-home-module         | 160.14 kB

modules-content-pages-content-pages-module.js                                  | modules-content-pages-content-pages-module                                  |  26.83 kB

vendors~modules-content-pages-content-pages-module.js                          | vendors~modules-content-pages-content-pages-module                          |  24.15 kB

modules-home-home-module.js                                                    | modules-home-home-module                                                    |   4.84 kB

Comment: Welcome to SO: In General: Please provide error logs, access logs and most important your NGINX configuration.

Comment: Thank you @TimoStark , I don't have any error logs. Sorry to ask, what should I provide for access log?

Comment: @TimoStark, should I send you the website url?

Comment: You can connect with my via Discord my handle is on my profile page.

Comment: Hey it was nginx issue, was not responding quickly on second subsequent request found the exact question on stackoverflow so I am gonna delete this. Thanx for your time.